# Kivy package for windows gives ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package my kivy app to windows, and have followed the instructions in http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html. This works fine for the touchtracer example, but it looks like the method is not sufficent to my app. The app uses ortc (http://framework.realtime.co/messaging/#python), which causes the problem. The line

```
ortc.OrtcClient().connect(app_key, private_key)
```

gives the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 15, in
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.
>   py", line 270, in load_module
>        exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\TouchApp\build\touchtracer\out00-PYZ.pyz\menu", line 17, in
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.
>   py", line 270, in load_module
>        exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\TouchApp\build\touchtracer\out00-PYZ.pyz\game", line 28, in
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.
>   py", line 270, in load_module
>        exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\TouchApp\build\touchtracer\out00-PYZ.pyz\sync", line 63, in
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\TouchApp\build\touchtracer\out00-PYZ.pyz\ortc", line 381, in
>    connect
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\TouchApp\build\touchtracer\out00-PYZ.pyz\websocket._core", l
>   ine 102, in create_connection
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\TouchApp\build\touchtracer\out00-PYZ.pyz\websocket._core", l
>   ine 250, in connect
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\TouchApp\build\touchtracer\out00-PYZ.pyz\websocket._http", l
>   ine 68, in connect
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\TouchApp\build\touchtracer\out00-PYZ.pyz\websocket._http", l
>   ine 128, in _ssl_socket
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\TouchApp\build\touchtracer\out00-PYZ.pyz\ssl", line 891, in
>   wrap_socket
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\TouchApp\build\touchtracer\out00-PYZ.pyz\ssl", line 566, in
>   **init**
>
> File "C:\Kivy190\TouchApp\build\touchtracer\out00-PYZ.pyz\ssl", line 788, in
>   do_handshake
>    ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.
>   c:581)

The .spec file looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import install_hooks
import os

def getResource(identifier, *args, **kwargs):

    if identifier == 'pygame_icon.tiff':
        raise IOError()
    return _original_getResource(identifier, *args, **kwargs)

install_hooks(globals())

a = Analysis(['card_game\\main.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Kivy190\\TouchApp'],
         hiddenimports=[],
         runtime_hooks=None)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='touchtracer.exe',
      debug=False,
      strip=None,
      upx=True,
      console=True )

coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('card_game\\'), Tree([f for f in os.environ.get('KIVY_SDL2_PATH', '').split(';') if 'bin' in f][0]),
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=None,
           upx=True,
           name='touchtracer')
```

Am I missing something? The python code works fine before pyinstaller is used.

Comment: Is there a certificate you're using that's not being included? It seems pretty cut and dry that it's a failed certificate verification.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, the error message says so, but I don't understand why it happens. I don't need to think about the vertification process when running the python code (the realtime ortc handles this), but when packaging the app using pyinstaller it does not work. So it seems that I am missing something when using pyinstaller.